# Best way to write views for multiple queries in Django?

Tags: python, django, list, view

It's a simple question. I've organised my models so that most objects served to the page are of one type - Item. The model contains various attributes which help me serve it in different ways.

I have articles, and videos, which are determined by a 'type' field on the model. Type = 'article' etc.

I have a listview, which shows all the objects in the Item model, sorted by date.

```
class ItemListView(generic.ListView):

    # This handles the logic for the UserForm and ProfileForm - without it, nothing happens.
    def item(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return index(request)

    def get_queryset(self):
        # return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
        return Item.objects.all().order_by('-create_date')
```

I want a view which shows all the articles, sorted by date, and all the videos, sorted by date. I have a feeling I'll be writing many more such views.

Is there a better way to do it than to write a new view for every single query? As, this is what I'm currently doing:

```
Views.py

class ItemListViewArticle(generic.ListView):

    # This handles the logic for the UserForm and ProfileForm - without it, nothing happens.
    def item(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return index(request)

    def get_queryset(self):
        # return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
        return Item.objects.filter(type__contains='article').order_by('-create_date')

class ItemListViewVideo(generic.ListView):

    # This handles the logic for the UserForm and ProfileForm - without it, nothing happens.
    def item(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return index(request)

    def get_queryset(self):
        # return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
        return Item.objects.filter(type__contains='video').order_by('-create_date')
```

```
urls.py

    path('new/', views.ItemListView.as_view(), name='new_list'),
    path('new/articles', views.ItemListViewArticle.as_view(), name='article_list'),
    path('new/videos', views.ItemListViewVideo.as_view(), name='video_list'),
```

Comment: There's nothing in the code you have posted that will ever call the `item` methods. Unless there is some other code that you haven't included in your question, you should remove it.

Comment: I'm calling them from a dropdown in the template - a simple href link to the view.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. You can't call methods directly from the template - your browser make arequest, Django passes that to a view, and the view can call methods. If you don't have *Python* code that is calling that `item` method, then it isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [URL querystring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)(ie **[request.GET](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET)**) to get type of the item from url and filter by it. Like this:

```
path('new/', views.ItemListView.as_view(), name='new_list'),


class ItemListViewArticle(generic.ListView):

    def item(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return index(request)

    def get_queryset(self):
        content_type = self.request.GET.get('type')
        return Item.objects.filter(type__contains=content_type).order_by('-create_date')

# usage
localhost:8000/new/?type=article
localhost:8000/new/?type=video
```

Or you can use [URL parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/) to get the type of data:

```
path('new/<str:content_type>/', views.ItemListView.as_view(), name='new_list'),

class ItemListViewArticle(generic.ListView):

    def item(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return index(request)

    def get_queryset(self):
        content_type = self.kwargs.get('content_type')
        return Item.objects.filter(type__contains=content_type).order_by('-create_date')

# usage
localhost:8000/new/article/
localhost:8000/new/video/
```

Comment: Thanks -  the second option worked great. I haven't seen that before, so that was very useful. Getting information from the URL is really useful, it can keep things much more organised in the views!