# I need a good way to divide a list in Django list view

Tags: django, django-views

I'm making a student management program.

Currently, the paging and search function have been coded as query and it works in combination, but since we receive new students every year, `school_year` is important.

I want to see the student list by `school_year` that I want by pressing the year on the top right.

I've been thinking about implementing it as a query, but it seems too complicated (I think it's too complicated to combine with the queries that have already been created), and it's too unnecessary to make a listview for each grade.

pls give me some good idea or solution

[listveiw template IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCRHh.png)

views.py:

```
class StudentList(ListView):

    model = Student
    template_name = 'student/orders.html'
    context_object_name = 'students'
    paginate_by = 12


    def get_queryset(self):
        keyword = self.request.GET.get('keyword')

        if keyword:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=keyword) | Q(email__icontains=keyword) | Q(student_mobile__icontains=keyword)
            )
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.all()

        return object_list


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StudentList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        paginator = context['paginator']
        page_numbers_range = 5  # Display only 5 page numbers
        max_index = len(paginator.page_range)

        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        current_page = int(page) if page else 1

        start_index = int((current_page - 1) / page_numbers_range) * page_numbers_range
        end_index = start_index + page_numbers_range
        if end_index >= max_index:
            end_index = max_index

        page_range = paginator.page_range[start_index:end_index]
        context['page_range'] = page_range

        # for combine filterign and paging
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389848/how-can-i-use-pagination-with-django-filter
        if self.request.GET.get('keyword'):
            keyword = self.request.GET.copy()
            if self.request.GET.get('page'):
                del keyword['page']
            context['keyword'] = keyword.urlencode()

        return context


class StudentDetail(DetailView):
    model = Student
    template_name = 'student/member.html'
    context_object_name = 'student'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['pk'] = Student.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your search page you can add selector with all possible years. Then, in your get_queryset_data add this:

```
year = self.request.GET.get('name_of_the_year_selector')
if year:
    object_list = object_list.filter(year=int(year))
return object_list
```

2. If you want specific url for each year then you should add another path into urls.py:

```
path('student/<int:year>/, StudentsList.as_view(), 'students-by-year')
```

Then you can try to add this code into your StudentList:

```
def setup(self, **kwargs):
     self.year = kwargs['year']
def get_queryset(self)
    if self.year:
        return self.model.objects.filter(year=int(self.year)
    if keyword:
....
```

Comment: Thanks i have a quastion there's no way to use URL parameter to get the type of data? like this     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56109878/best-way-to-write-views-for-multiple-queries-in-django

Comment: Since you are submitting GET form, the year will appear in the URL if you add that selector into the form. Is it what you want?

Comment: no i mean i want to do like this     https://localhost:8000/student/school_year/
         https://localhost:8000/student/other_school_year/

Comment: currently, i use only one page like localhost:8000/student/

Comment: Please see edits, some modifications may be required.

Comment: check it out how i made it

Answer (score 0):

i made it. thanks Borzenko

view.py

```
def get_queryset(self): #context over writing
    keyword = self.request.GET.get('keyword')
    school_year = self.kwargs.get('school_year')
    school_year = str(school_year)

    if keyword:
        object_list = self.model.objects.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=keyword) | Q(email__icontains=keyword) | 
        Q(student_mobile__icontains=keyword)
        ).filter(school_year=school_year)
    else:
        object_list = self.model.objects.all().filter(school_year=school_year)

    return object_list
```

urls.py

```
path('student/<str:school_year>/', views.StudentList.as_view(), name='student_list'),
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and the simplest paginator that I have ever seen is `uni_paginator`

**Disclaimer. I am author of it.**

You can start using it, or dive into the code and see how it works. Be happy to answer any questions.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/mrvol/uni_paginator)

Good luck!